# How to close "Conque GDB" window inside VIM?

Tags: vim, gdb, window, exit, conque

I've just install vim plugin named "Conque gdb", it's good: but after I type "q" in gdb, the "Conque gdb" window is still there, hang.

How can I, say, type "q" inside gdb so that Conque gdb window is automatically closed inside vim?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your vimrc you need:

```
let g:ConqueTerm_CloseOnEnd = 1
```

Personally, I use the following settings:

```
let g:ConqueTerm_StartMessages = 0
let g:ConqueTerm_Color = 0
let g:ConqueTerm_CloseOnEnd = 1
let g:ConqueTerm_Interrupt = '<C-g><C-c>'
let g:ConqueTerm_ReadUnfocused = 1
```